# Average of several different fields from one stream

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming

I haven't chosen a streaming framework yet but I'm messing around with Flink right now. But, I'm open to using Beam, Spark Streaming, whatever I figure out fits my usecase. How would you do the equivalent of the following SQL:

```
SELECT a,b,c, avg(d), avg(e), ..., avg(z)
FROM whatever
GROUP BY a,b,c,d,e, ..., z
```

It seems that for Flink doing an average is accomplished through an AggregateFunction https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/AggregateFunction.java#L61

But I don't see how you make this 'scale'. This appears to be a lot of boilerplate just for an average of a single field. What if I have several different streams with various fields I need to average?

Do any of: Flink, Beam, Structured Streaming, etc make this any easier?

As a side note, is there an easy way to emulate this nice little count filter syntax from Postgres,

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS unfiltered,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE some_condition) AS filtered
FROM whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally in flink jobs, I would create defined user functions as separate classes, which I can then apply to whatever fields I like. Flink also has a SQL API, which I am not as familiar with, but here is an example based on code I found here (https://gist.github.com/mustafaakin/457859b8bf703c64029071c1139b593d):

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

StreamTableEnvironment table = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
DataStream<String> text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999, "\n");
DataStream<Tuple3<String, Double, Time>> dataset = text.map(...);

table.registerDataStream("dataset", dataset, "p1, p2, p3");
String query = "SELECT p1, AVG(p2) AS avgp2 FROM dataset GROUP p1";
Table tableResult = table.sql(query);

// print to System.out
table.toAppendStream(tableResult, Row.class).print();

env.execute();
```

I would also look at Apache Ignite for streaming data with SQL queries. I've never used it myself, but I've heard good things.